# How to make forums quote system in PHP?

Tags: php

There's a problem with my forums quote system because when I quote any user message with quotes (" or '), it does ignore the message quote box.

I made it with PHP together to JavaScript:

When I click in quote button, it calls a function which adds the current quoted message to self user message box.

```
quoteUserMessage("<? echo $replyauthordata['username']; ?>", "<? echo $replydata['message']; ?>");
```

And I think the quote box could generate the message ID, but I don't know how can I generate the message text from the message ID with **PHP preg_replace**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dumping text from PHP directly into a Javascript context, which means your PHP output is becoming unknown/undefined Javascript varaibles:

```
quoteUserMessage(fred, Hi Mom!);
```

You should NEVEr directly output from PHP into JS. Always use json_encode:

```
quoteUserMessage(<?php echo json_encode($replyauthordata['name']) ?>, ...
```

which would produce

```
quoteUserMessage('fred', 'Hi mom!');
```

Comment: No... it does not works, but thanks! I forget add "" between the example codes in my question.